# Need help to rotate a 3D point around a line and find the coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations

How do I solve this?:

Rotate p=[2,1,3] 60 degrees anti-clockwise around the line from a=[1,-1,1] to b=[3,-3,3]. What is the coordinates of p'?

The first thing I've to do is to find vector AB and then the length of vector AB then what?

Comment: Can you use the rotation matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix?